# How to create a "distance to the top" for the center of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying center an image so the middle of the image is equal to the center of the paragraph as I change the size of the screen. To have the paragraph and expanded image show up, click on the picture of Roger Federer. Once it shows up, you can see my problem. The paragraph can get smaller in width and stay a consistant height, but the image can't otherwise it gets cut off. Therefore, I make the image smaller in width, but then the height compared to the paragraph is no longer equal (center to center). I can't figure out how to make each center at the same height. Let me know if you guys need more info, or if you guys know how to do this. Thanks.

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
  

}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
}

.column img:hover {
  background-color:black;
  filter: brightness(70%);
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 50px;
  left:30px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  border: 4.5px solid rgb(84, 104, 217);
  border-radius:4px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  border: 4.5px solid rgb(84, 104, 217);
  border-radius:4px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:400px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:400px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  border: 4.5px solid rgb(84, 104, 217);
  border-radius:4px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  border: 4.5px solid rgb(84, 104, 217);
  border-radius:4px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:700px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:700px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  border: 4.5px solid rgb(84, 104, 217);
  border-radius:4px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:700px;
    padding-bottom:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:700px;
    margin-bottom:500px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  border: 4.5px solid rgb(84, 104, 217);
  border-radius:4px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:50px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'> Parapraph #6 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using flex box.

```
  #expanded-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
```

Remove the `postion: abosolute;` from both #expandedImg and #img-paragraph. And then change `expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";` to `expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";`

Read more about flex container here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container